# How to set Cell Height according to WebView text?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have a WebView With Custom Cell and i want to set height of both WebView Size as well as
Custom Cell Size according to WebView Text.

Text is display from the HTML File, so every time text size will be difference,
so please suggest me how can i done?

Answer (score 1):

You must implement the delegate method webViewDidFinishLoad, where you can get the view's height:

```
NSString *height = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.scrollHeight;"];
```

Now you can return that height in your cellHeightForRow.